# When citing a foreign-language article, do I need to translate the journal name?

Tags: citations, translations

Internet sources seem to agree that, in the list of references,  the title of an article written in a non-Latin script should be transliterated and also translated. Similarly, the title of the journal should be transliterated if necessary. My question is: **should non-English journal names should also be translated in the references?**

Comment: Many journals have official English name. Do you have this in the given situation?

Comment: Note, answers to this [related question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/43484/how-to-cite-sources-written-in-a-different-language-than-english) discuss how to deal with the title of the article, but do not address the journal name.

Answer (score 3):

I'm just guessing here, but have the following suggestion. If the journal, itself, provides a translation then use that. But otherwise, use the formal name that the journal uses no matter the script or language. The name is likely trademarked and also likely known worldwide by its official name. So use that name.

A journal regularly publishing in several languages, of course, might, theoretically at least, have official translations of its name. But otherwise, use the same form that they use.

Answer (score 1):

**There is no single way to do references.** There are many different formats (MLA, APA, Chicago, etc.) -- some publishers will specify a required format, others will not. Further, in many contexts, anything reasonably close to a standard format will not raise eyebrows.

**Both [APA](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2012/12/citing-translated-works-in-apa-style.html) and [MLA](https://guides.library.yale.edu/c.php?g=296262&p=1974230) conventions seem to say no, however.** Both of these seem to give the article title in the (1) original, (2) transliteration, and (3) translation, but give the journal title in transliteration only. If you are citing a translation of an original article, there are separate rules for that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best ways to find out which journal name you should use in your citations are:

1. open the article PDF/fulltext and check if it has a "How to cite" or similar section. If it does, then use that!
2. if you have time: write to the journal contact email address and ask. They are the most interested to be correctly cited.
3. if you're in a hurry, use the journal name that appears on the bibliographic legend, usually found in the article pages headers or footers.